# Unable to use javadoc -sourcepath with multiple paths

Tags: javadoc

I'm having trouble specifying multiple paths to the -sourcepath option of javadoc.  I have two trees:

```
  /hd/c/src/SerialPort/src/main/java/serialPort
  /hd/c/src/drivers/src/main/java/zigbee
```

The first tree contains a single package, down in:

```
/hd/c/src/SerialPort/src/main/java/serialPort/SerialPort
```

The second tree has numerous packages, in:

```
  /hd/c/src/drivers/src/main/java/zigbee/stack
  /hd/c/src/drivers/src/main/java/zigbee/common
  /hd/c/src/drivers/src/main/java/zigbee/zcl
```

I can successfully create documents for either tree by saying:

```
  javadoc -d ./doc/serialPort \
    -sourcepath SerialPort/src/main/java \
    -subpackages serialPort
```

and

```
  javadoc -d ./doc/drivers 
    -sourcepath drivers/src/main/java \
    -subpackages zigbee
```

What I want is to create a single, set of documents for the whole works.  It feels to me as if I should be able to say:

```
  javadoc -d ./doc \
    -sourcepath SerialPort/src/main/java;drivers/src/main/java \
    -subpackages \
      serialPort \
      zigbee
```

but any attempt to place multiple paths in my -sourcepath results in this message:

```
  javadoc: error - No packages or classes specified.
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For all the packages in the current directory:

`javadoc -d doc -subpackages .`

`.` implies the current directory.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Just a friendly suggestion, you can format inline code using backticks. For example, `javadoc -d doc -subpackages .` Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what platform uses `/hd/c` as a path, but I'm guessing something Unix based - possibly a Mac. In which case, you should be using `:` as your path separator, not `;`

Comment: I'm running under Windows XP, using Cygwin.  Is that likely to be the problem?  I've tried using semi-colons (;) and colons (:) and even commas (,).  No joy.

Comment: Cygwin?! You're on your own, mate! :-) I'd start by trying to get it working with a single path, so you can make sure you've got all the rest of the parameters/setup right, then add the extra path elements in the knowledge that the only thing that can be wrong at that point is the path setup.

Comment: I am able to build either set of documents (using the commands shown above).  It's only when I try to place two paths on the -sourcepath that I get problems.

Comment: Oh yeah, you said that. Sorry, I missed it. Hmmm... out of ideas, I'm afraid. Perhaps using subpackages which refer to different source trees is confusing it? But I really am just guessing now. Sorry.

Comment: I haven't been able to confirm, from the various on-line documents I've read, whether subpackages in different source trees are supported.  Possibly I should be using the -link option instead?  But I haven't been able to get that to do what I expect either...

Comment: I was finally able to confirm that everything worked fine under Linux; it's a problem with Javadoc under Cygwin.

Comment: Thanks. So, no solution under cygwin?